# Would my reply be seen by all people to whom an original email was sent?

Tags: gmail

I never understood how this works, so I try to ask here.

If from someone I receive an email that is sent to many people (the case where Gmail shows "to so-and-so, so-and-so, ...), and if I reply to that email directly, then would everyone else get my reply too or just the original sender will receive it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your e-mail will be always delivered to the ones you've sent it**

It's not a joke, it's really so easy: whenever you answer to a mail (forward one, write a new one) you just need to check "To", "Cc" (and sometimes "Bcc") lines to see who will receive it.

Your e-mail won't be sent to anybody not listed there. (of course it can be forwarded by your recipients but I suppose it's not your issue now).

[image]

### Update

> if someone A sends an email to me and others B, C, and if I reply to A directly, then B and C will see my reply too??

- If you click "reply" and only A's address will be added to "To", then only A will receive it
- If you click "reply all" and all of their adress will be added, then all of them will receive it.

Again, all you need to do is to check those fields before sending the mail.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I have not yet understood your answer. You mean: if someone A sends an email to me and others B, C, and if I reply to A directly, then B and C will see my reply too?? This is my issue. :)